# How can I write the data in Firestore to Google Sheet with app script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, google-docs

I have a problem with app script. I try to add my data to Google Sheet but I can't do it. Firstly, I get my data from Firestore. It returns the Document or Document[] variables. So how can I access inside of this variable and write to my Google Sheet? I didn't find anything about for that.
Here is my function:

```
function myFunction(){

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);
  
  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("TEST");
  console.log(allDocuments.length);
}
```

Can you help me please? How can I read that data and write to my Google Sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [page](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) provides a link to the [wiki](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/wiki/Firestore-Method-Documentation), which contains a bit more info.

The [`getDocuments()`](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/wiki/Firestore-Method-Documentation#getdocuments) method returns an array of the documents in the collection. You just need to loop over this Array and do whatever you want with the documents in this array, e.g. update the Sheet cells.

For example, the following shows one possible approach to get the value of the `field1` field for each document:

```
const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("TEST");
for (var i = 0; i < allDocuments.length; i++) {    
    var field1Value = allDocuments[i].fields["field1"];       
    // ...
}
```

---

Based on your update I guess you want to build an array and pass it to appendRow().

The following should do the trick:

```
  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments("TEST");
  var myArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; I < allDocuments.length; i++){
    var chills = allDocuments[i].fields["chills"];
    myArray.push(chills.boolean);
  }
  sheet.appendRow(myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful for me but how can I get only value from this fieldValue? It returns like {boolean=false}. I need only false or true.

Comment: `allDocuments[i].fields["field1"].boolean` should do the trick. I would kindly suggest you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I'm new on the app script. It returns undefined. Do you have any suggestion? Also thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question (via the "edit" link at the bottom) and add your exact code?

Comment: I edited my question. App script so confused for me. Can you find a solution? Please, Renaud...

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I checked the update but it doesn't work. I look at the console.log chills boolean returns {boolean : false}. Also It doesn't write to the sheet. I can't still access to the only value of chills.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with the info you shared I cannot help you anymore. I would suggest you cut your problem into several pieces (update the sheet with constant, get data from Firestore, replace constants by Firestore data, etc...) and ask a question for each piece for which you encounter problems.